# Ajax not firing inside Modal Popup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, laravel-5

Currently I have a button to view cart contents as such:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-targets="showvendorcart1" data-target="#showvendorcartModal" data-async="true" data-cache="false" data-endpoint="vendor/showcart/{{$vendorid}}">SHOW CART</a>
```

**data-target** is for my modal

**data-targets** is for the body of my modal after the ajax endpoint returns a response

My Ajax code is as follows:

```
$('a[data-async="true"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        url = self.data('endpoint'),
        target = self.data('targets'),
        cache = self.data('cache');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache : cache,
        success: function(data){ 
            if (target !== 'undefined'){
                $('#'+target).html( data['response'] );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(courtesy of [jQuery and data-attributes to handle all ajax calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908592/jquery-and-data-attributes-to-handle-all-ajax-calls))

Now once the modal dialog popup has appeared I have some grid items inside a table such as:

```
<table id="itemstable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="fixed-header">
        <tr>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>' . $v->qty . '</td>
            <td>' . $v->sku . '</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-targets="showvendorcart1" data-async="true" data-cache="false" data-endpoint="vendor/removecart/' . $v->id . '">&nbsp;X&nbsp;</a>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I'm running into is I have another ajax endpoint call for each table line item but this time when I click it, the Ajax isn't firing at all. I looked at my browsers inspector but not even an error or attempt.

Am I missing something here because it's practically the same code I ran to get the popup and show the response in the body but now the only difference is I'm doing it inside the modal.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: The modal is dynamically generated and inserted into the DOM? If thats the case, `click()` won't work, you will need to use `on('click', function(){ ... })`.

Comment: @Jeemusu Yes thanks that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this and it should work.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-async="true"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your code here

});
```