# Getting data from server to show up in modal with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm doing my project about POS. Here is the example view of
it.

[image]

What I want to do is when I click the variant button, it should pop up modal with data from server where the menu id is selected. I have very little knowledge about Ajax, so I will be very glad if someone can guide me through this.

P.S I'm doing this with Laravel.

Comment: Try using this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908592/jquery-and-data-attributes-to-handle-all-ajax-calls

Answer (score 0):

For modals, you can use the bootstrap one  [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

The logic of the request can be handled through [JQuery Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

As for the laravel part, just extract your data and return it as JSON:

```
return response()->json($data);
```