# Pass data from anchor link to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm thinking of a way to reduce the amount of javascript/ajax code by enabling ajax on links from attributes (idea found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908592/jquery-and-data-attributes-to-handle-all-ajax-calls)).

The goal is to be able to make an ajax request by reusing the same javascript without editing it.

Everythings works great but I just can't figure out how to pass multiple data with the anchor link.

I'm trying with this

```
<a href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" 
    data-endpoint="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" 
    data-target="addtask .modal-content .panel-body"
    data-cache="false"
    data-async="true"
    data-parameters="[{{ $data1 }} , {{ $data2}}]" 
    >Add a task
</a>
```

And in another (static) view I have this script

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-async="true"]', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        url = self.data('endpoint'),
        target = self.data('target'),
        cache = self.data('cache'),  
        parameters = self.data('parameters'); //Probably not the best thing to do             

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache : cache,
        data : parameters, //To edit?
        success: function(data)
        { 
           if (target !== 'undefined'){ $('#'+target).html( data ); }
        }
    });
});
```

In my php script named `tasks.create`, I would like to use `$data1` and `$data2`. But I don't know how to achieve this. Any idea?

Or the whole idea is dumb and there is a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i'd use an opaque string from the javascript perspective.  first i'd find a reasonable separator which won't be in the data variables, i'll assume '|' works.

html

```
data-parameters="{{ $data1 }}|{{ $data2 }}"
```

php

```
$params = explode("|", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" 
    data-endpoint="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" 
    data-target="addtask .modal-content .panel-body"
    data-cache="false"
    data-async="true"

    data1-parameters='{!! json_encode($data1) !!}'
    data2-parameters='{!! json_encode($data2) !!}'

    >Add a task
</a>
```

And the ajax call:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-async="true"]', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        url = self.data('endpoint'),
        target = self.data('target'),
        cache = self.data('cache');             

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache : cache,
        data : {
            data1: self.attr('data1-parameters'),
            data2: self.attr('data2-parameters')
        },
        success: function(data)
        { 
           if (target !== 'undefined'){ $('#'+target).html( data ); }
        }
    });
});
```